# microsoft.graph.search Filter and Orderby

Tags: office365, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I have looked here https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search and at the odata query parameters listed here http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/query_parameters.

Can anyone offer some guidance on how to filter out folders when searching your OneDrive For Business files using the graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/microsoft.graph.search endpoint and how to get orderby to work.  It seems pretty simple, but I can't seem to find the syntax.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph REST doesn't support to filter the folders or files directly. You can use OneDrive REST api as a workaround. Here is an example for your reference:

```
GET: drive/root/children?filter=folder+ne+null
```

And below the URL root for the service:
[image]
More detail about OneDrive REST, please refer to [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm). And if you want the Microsoft Graph also support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com).

Comment: Thanks, looks like OneDrive For Business has limitations on filter, so folder doesn't seem to work.  Plus, I have tried the orderby on name from the "GET /drive/root/view.search?q=vacation" request syntax, using "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/view.search?q=find&orderby=name%20asc" and it does not sort by name.

I just must be missing a piece of the puzzle because all I want to do is search the onedrive for business files and sort them by name without returning folders.

Comment: I am also not able to using the order by via search action for OneDrive for business(both OneDrive REST and Microsoft Graph). It seems not supported yet. You may leave the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) if you want to Microsoft Graph to support this orderby.

Answer (score 1):

Now Microsoft Graph API supports, filtering and ordering the items in onedrive.
Use the below Graph endpoint to retrieve the folders from root of the onedrive,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$filter=folder ne null
```

To order the folders in descending order, use the Graph API in below format,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children?$filter=folder ne null&orderby=name desc
```

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive API (and Graph API on drives) do not support filtering or ordering results from the /search API. I'll add this to our list of requested features to consider for a future update. In the mean time, you would need to do sorting / filtering of results data client side.